# Parameters not passed correctly from Portlet (Liferay) to public WebService (ConvertTemperature)

Tags: web-services, jsp, post, liferay, portlet

I am new to Portlet development and I am running into an annoying issue with Liferay.

I have played around a bit and created the following portlet (.jsp) page based on the "edit.jsp" from the "My-Greeting" tutorial:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<%

PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String Temperature = (String)prefs.getValue("Temperature","Temperature");

PortletPreferences prefs2 = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String FromUnit = (String)prefs2.getValue("FromUnit", "FromUnit");

PortletPreferences prefs3 = renderRequest.getPreferences();
String ToUnit = (String)prefs3.getValue("ToUnit","ToUnit");



%>



<portlet:renderURL var="editGreetingURL">

    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:form action="http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx/ConvertTemp" method="post">

    <aui:input label="Temperature" name="Temperature" type="text" value="<%= Temperature %>" />
    <aui:input label="FromUnit" name="FromUnit" type="text" value="<%= FromUnit %>" />
    <aui:input label="ToUnit" name="ToUnit" type="text" value="<%= ToUnit %>" />
    <aui:button label="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</aui:form>

<portlet:renderURL var="viewGreetingURL">

    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view.jsp" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<p><a href="<%= viewGreetingURL %>">Back</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This portlet is supposed to take 3 input parameters: Temperature, FromUnit and ToUnit and then pass them on to a public WebService which converts Temperatures for example from Fahrenheit to Celcius (see http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL) .

The portlet renders the input fields correctly and when I click the submit button it also tries to execute the Webservice but it doesn't actually pass on the parameters it seems because I get the following error response from the WebService itself:

System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: Temperature.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

So even though my portlet has the input field Temperature it doesn't seem to actually pass it on and attach it to the action URL in the post ...

ne more thing, I replaced the "post" with a "get" and the URL string looks like this:

http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx/ConvertTemp?_mygreeting_WAR_mygreetingportlet_formDate=1377389917227&_mygreeting_WAR_mygreetingportlet_Temperature=30&_mygreeting_WAR_mygreetingportlet_FromUnit=degreeFahrenheit&_mygreeting_WAR_mygreetingportlet_ToUnit=degreeCelsius

What am I doing wrong here? Clearly it seems to be passing on the wrong parameters...

Answer (score 0):

- Your portlet's jsps must not have a `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` section, that's the business of the portal. You only generate fragments of the whole page in your portlets
- When you use `<aui:form>` and `<aui:input>`, AlloyUI is aware of it being run in a portal, thus it adds the portlet namespace to the parameter names - that's what you see in the GET URL you're quoting. (simply use `<form>` and `<input>` if you indeed want to post to an external site from your portal)
- If you check http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx/ConvertTemp?&Temperature=30&FromUnit=degreeFahrenheit&ToUnit=degreeCelsius, you will see that this replies with a webservice-like results, e.g. `<double>-1.1111111111110859</double>`, so most likely you don't want to have this as the form's post target, but rather implement your portlet to reach out the the service and display the result embedded in your portlet's output. How to do this exceeds the scope of this answer though
- just related: You can get all preferences just from your `prefs` object, no need for `prefs2` and `prefs3`, and you're not using the `editGreetingURL`, right?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers, this is much appreciated! The HTML code within the jsp came from Liferay's own example (the My Greeting Portlet sample)... I didn't know that it shouldn't be there.

So you are saying that I can't use aui:form to post parameters to an external webservice at all then?

How would you implement it so that the result is embedded in the portlet just out of curiousity?

Comment: You probably want to post back to your portlet's actionURL, have your portlet contact the external webservice (or a cache) and then generate an output that includes the result on the main portlet output - rather than posting to an external site, completely moving to that site. Where did you find the "My Greeting Portlet"? I guess this result is just from the standard jsp boilerplate that eclipse add when you create a new jsp, but you must not have the mentioned tags in the portal world - you just generate a fragment of that page.

Comment: ok, found the "my greeting" portlet. Indeed, it does not contain the tags, but the instructions to create the files. So you most likely ended up with eclipse's boilerplate on the page.

Comment: Hi Olaf, yes that is exactly what I want to do. I did some more research and it looks like I will have to use AJAX and jquery for that, I added another answer , but the issue I have with that solution is that whilst it will prevent the redirection to the external site, I still don't know how to actually post the response from the webservice I am calling... this solution posts a bespoke message as you see. How do I embed the actual response from the service?